# Protecting Routes with Role Permissions using middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have a multilevel members website and need to protect my routes in the web.php file in Laravel 5.5.

I have a column on my users table called `role_id`.

In `role_id` is the following values

- NULL (For New Users)
- 1 (For Owner)
- 2 (For Admin)
- 3 (For Moderators)
- 4 (For Banned Users)

I was trying to do it with a simple IF statement

```
if (Auth::user()->role_id != '2'):
    return view('home');
    else:
//ADMIN ROUTES
    Route::get('/admin','AdminController@index')->name('admin');
endif;

if (Auth::user()->role_id != '1'):
    return view('home');
    else:
//OWNER ROUTES
    Route::get('/admin','OwnerController@index')->name('owner');
endif;
ETC....
```

> But get Error Trying to get property of non-object. Also probably not the best way to do that.

So I read about doing it with MIDDLEWARE like this: (Looks much better)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function() {
    // put all your admin routes here
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'owner']], function() {
    // put all your owner user routes here
});
```

But it didn't explain how to add the Middleware. 
Would I have to create 5 different Middleware files for each group similar to file I found:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Admin
{
    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($this->auth->user()->role_id != '2') {
            return redirect()->view('home');
        }
        return $next($request);        
    }
}
```

Could someone lend a helping hand and explain how to write the correct middleware to achieve this?

Comment: make sure that `Auth::user()` is not null..

Comment: It is null, and I'm logged in as Admin. Why is that?

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object` means that somewhere you're trying to do `$foo->bar` but `$foo` isn't an object.

Comment: sorry @echo, i just skim over your code and notice that only `Auth::user()` or `$this->auth->user()` might return nulls. @Scuzzy is right, perhaps you can post the stacktrace so we can find who is actually throwing `Trying to get property of non-object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function() {
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', function(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });
});
```

into protected $routeMiddleware of Kernel.php

```
'admin'      => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
```

AdminMiddleware.php

```
$user = Auth::user();
if($user->role == 'admin'){
    return $next($request);
} else
    // abort(403, 'Wrong Accept Header');
    return new Response(view('notauthorized')->with('role', 'admin'));

}
```

admin, moderators, owner, banned_user will be value of user_type/role column of user table.
    or you can use `user_type_id` or `role_id` instead of `user_type_name` or `role_type`

Don't forget to add

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
```

just under the

```
use Closure;
```

of your Middleware

You can also do it with other ways like Gate, let me know if you need it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Error Trying to get property of non-object. Can be found if user not logged in yet.

Before u check

`if (Auth::user()->role_id != '2'):`

u should make sure that user is logged in with

`Auth::check()`

first...

Answer (score 0):

Like this example:

```
 Route::get('/cart/payment', 'CartController@getcartpayment')->middleware('checkAuth');


 $user = Sentinel::findById($user_id);
        $role= $user->role();
```